# Preventing XSS attacks in React and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, security, xss

I'm developing a simple post application using the `React` for a *front-end* and `NodeJS` + `MySQL` for *back-end*. Considering the security I'm wondering where the user input sanitizing should take place - on the client side on the `React` *form* component level or rather on the server side in the `NodeJS` code after the user sends the data? I'm asking especially about the `xss` attacks , for example to prevent for posting a `JS` code as a post content/body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't sanitize on the client-side *before* the data is sent to the server - clients are free to run whatever JavaScript validation code they want (including none), and to POST to your server whatever they want.

A good approach is to sanitize as soon as safely possible. Doing this will result in your database storing sanitized values, which means that security will not depend on also remembering to sanitize on the client whenever rendering something from the database. There wouldn't be any harm in also sanitizing on the client when rendering, though - it wouldn't add any noticeable overhead, and would provide an extra layer in case you had an endpoint that you mistakenly didn't sanitize before saving to the database.

Comment: So You mean that for e.g. instead of sanitizing the user post content on the `onSubmit `handler (so just before the data is being sent to the server) I should rather sanitize the post content received from the server on the render method on the client side (React)?

Comment: Absolutely don't sanitize `onSubmit`. It'll work in most cases, but not if someone is deliberately trying to exploit you. Yes, sanitize either on the server, or when rendering the post contents, or both.

Comment: Ok, but can You please explain me why should't I sanitize `onSubmit`? What do You mean by "someone is deliberately trying to exploit you"!?

Comment: It's trivial for a client to fiddle with the JavaScript that your server tells them to run, and to run the client's own JavaScript instead. If the client does such a thing, they could easily completely skip your validation step - or, even easier, submit malicious data directly to your endpoint, without any sanitization.

Comment: If the user can fiddle with the JavaScript send from the server what's the point with sanitizing on render on client side as You stated earlier?

Comment: (1) If you've sanitized on the server too, it'll be OK anyway (2) Even if you didn't, if the user knows JavaScript, tries to fiddle around with the payloads you send to them, and decides to remove the part where they get sanitized, that's completely on them. Only someone who's deliberately trying to change around your site's internals would be at risk, and at that point, if they run into any issue, it's completely their fault, and not something you should (or even could) protect against.

Comment: So sanitizing ONLY on render on client side (without previously on server site) is pointless because the user that knows JS can always manipulate the JS code received from the server, right?!?

Comment: No, sanitizing only on the client when rendering is all right. The only thing to worry about is, if you accidentally *don't* sanitize in one section of the app when rendering, and the database isn't sanitized, then you'll have a security risk. If the app is large enough that this sort of misstep is a possibility, doing it both on the server and on the client when rendering should alleviate all concerns, because then *both* would have to have incorrect logic for XSS to get through.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a little confused now. If as You have previously said "if the user knows JavaScript, tries to fiddle around with the payloads you send to them, and decides to remove the part where they get sanitized" what's the point on sanitizing on the client side(when  rendering)!?

Comment: It's a non-issue for ordinary legitimate users. If someone does deliberately fiddle with the code that makes the payload safe to render, they're essentially assuming all responsibility. If I had a link to your site, I could go there, then open up the browser console, and type `while (true);` and lock up my computer. That's not remotely your fault, nor is it something worth trying to protect against. This is the same sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are letting React do the DOM manipulation itself rather than doing it by hand imperatively you don't have a lot to worry about. As long as you stay away from things like [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) or mutating the DOM by hand.

That being said, there are some things that you can adopt to make it even safer like using [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) when you have no alternative to dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

You could also sanitize user generated content before persisting it to the database to not only prevent XSS but any sort of RCE if you know these values might be consumed by other programs and want to be defensive. But for XSS in React I wouldn't worry too much, It's only through the escape hatches in React that you would manage to get yourselve into an XSS issue.

Here is a good read on the topic https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/react-xss-guide-examples-and-prevention